# Void value not ignored as it ought to be Error

Tags: c++

I am using Doubly Linked List Data Structure of CPP and have written the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;


int main()
{
        
    
    list <int> l1[64]; 
    l1[1].push_back(100);
    l1[2].push_back(200);
    int p=l1[1].pop_front();
    cout<<p<<endl;
     p=l1[2].pop_front();
    cout<<p<<endl;
    

}
```

But I am getting this errors-->

```
trial.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
trial.cpp:15:23: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   15 |  int p=l1[1].pop_front();
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
trial.cpp:17:20: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   17 |   p=l1[2].pop_front();
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I am unable to understand the reason for this error, because I am just popping the first element into the **p** variable and printing it. Then why am I getting this error?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front Doesn't need a long read to spot the problem in your code.

Comment: @CODEGEEK Well not me, but I guess the problem is the lack of research effort. If you had looked it up you would have seen that `pop_front` does not return anything, and even if you hadn't looked it up the compiler is telling you the same thing.

Comment: see also [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: the ```pop_front()``` does not return any value and that's what the compiler is telling you. You cannot assign ```pop_front()``` to a variable because it is a void function.

Comment: You're getting this error because you guessed at what `pop_front()` does instead of reading the documentation. Even if you make a habit if guessing, once your guess is shown to be wrong, your next stop should be to look up what the function actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop_front` does not return anything. The reason is that it would be impossible to implement the [strong exception safety guarantee](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/imprint_downloads/informit/aw/meyerscddemo/DEMO/MAGAZINE/SU_FRAME.HTM) if it did. To access the front element of your list use `front`. Here's your code rewritten.

```
int main()
{    
    list <int> l1[64]; 
    l1[1].push_back(100);
    l1[2].push_back(200);
    int p=l1[1].front();
    l1[1].pop_front();
    cout<<p<<endl;
    p=l1[2].front();
    l1[2].pop_front();
    cout<<p<<endl;
}
```